# Interfere Win32 message loop with injected DLL code (SetWindowsHookEx)

Tags: c++, c, dll, winapi, code-injection

**Hello everybody!**

After hours of penetrating Google I ended up here. I'll come straight to the point: I'm about to "refresh" my C/C++ skills and gain experience with the unmanaged world again. As a "basic" task I developed a little key logger (which are just a few lines with the Windows API) but now I want to extend it with a "stealth" feature. Therefor I threw the code into a Win32 DLL [it's content you find here](http://pastebin.com/jre4Mbft). As you will notice, there is a very problematic part in it:

```
  MSG msg;
 BOOL bRet;

 while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
 { 
  if (bRet == -1)
  {
   return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
   TranslateMessage(&msg); 
   DispatchMessage(&msg); 
  }
 }
```

Yes, it's an ordinary message loop - which causes trouble in my case. I inject this DLL into a "victim" executable (e.g. VLC media player) to fool AV/Application firewalls and it works so far, the injection itself passes flawlessly. Now comes the big BUT: of course the endless while-loop now freezes the whole target application (without it, my hook callback never gets executed) which wasn't really planed... After diving through half of the MSDN library and trying a lot of "solutions" Google gave me; I give up.

*Is it even possible to evaluate the message loop of the "victim" process without blocking it's own business but providing my keyboard hook callback to work?*

Sincerely yours,
Nefarius

Comment: Does it do this will all targets or just VLC?

Comment: I get "Unknown paste ID, it may have expired or been deleted!" when trying to view the pastebin code.

Comment: Just tried with PuTTY, Thunderbird, couldn't inject into Windows Calculator, WinRAR crashes too, Notepad++ crashes... but all of them log to the specified file until i kill them with process/task-manager.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I corrected the pastebin-link.

Comment: "Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process" http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx

Comment: I know the project you linked, I'm injecting with medthod No. 2: "The CreateRemoteThread & LoadLibrary Technique" via a separate Win32 console application. This works so far...

Comment: GetMessage will never return -1 since you are passing NULL for the hwnd param.  It will return 0 when it processes a WM_QUIT.

Comment: Yes, thats also why I want to solve this another way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, first off, you're doing way too much in your dll entry point function. For one thing  - and this is straight from MSDN - "There are serious limits on what you can do in a DLL entry point". Also, while in the dll entry point the loader lock is held so no other libraries can be loaded/unloaded. So seeing as you're running your message loop (by calling *InstallHook()*) in the DLL entry point, you're really throwing a stick in the bicycle spokes, so the speak.

Now with that out of the way, getting it to work is pretty simple. When the DLL is loaded, create a new thread at *InstallHook* and you should be good to go. Now you're message loop will be in it's own thread with it's own message queue (or at least it should, windows messaging still kinda confuses me).

```
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  CreateThread( NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)InstallHook, (void*)NULL, 0, NULL );
```

Comment: Ahhh, you know what? I already tried it with a separate Thread, BUT I only put the message loop in it and left the SetWindowsHookEx() in the DllMain function call. Thank you so much, I wasted hours with this little detail.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a message loop there. The application you're injecting into already has a message loop (unless it's a console app, which doesn't deal with messages anyway). Just let your hook do its thing when the host's message loop processes its messages as it normally would.

Comment: I alerady tried it without the loop, but then I have the problem that my callback function never gets executed.

Comment: I also have the same problem too. The SetWindowsHookEx() returns 0, but the callback function won't execute at all. Is there any reason for that?